# Netezza - How to convert timestamp/datetime to 13-digit UNIX time millis?

Tags: sql, datetime, unix-timestamp, netezza

I have read some reference about Netezza, but I cannot figure out how to convert timestamp/datetime value to 13-digit UNIX time millis.

Any suggestion or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres offers the `extract(epoch from . . .)` function that does exactly what you want:

```
select extract(epoch from <datetimecol>) * 1000
```

This has been in Postgres for a long time, so I would guess that Netezza also supports it.

Comment: But in order to get the 13-digit timestamp, the extracted number should be multiplied by 1000:)
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM <datetimecol>)*1000 FROM ...